# No desktop or metro after logged into a New user account in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, login

I am using Windows 8 Pro x64 Version.
When I create a new user account (Admin or non Admin), and try to log in, neither Desktop nor metro interface is not loading. However I can log into Windows 8 using the same account, and start other programs like Internet Explorer or Firefox using the task manager. I tried running explorer.exe from the task manager but it is not running (no error is showing, but is not running). I tried with both local accounts and Microsoft Acccounts. but both are not loading the desktop or metro. I can see the "Hi" and other screens for the first time login as usual.

I haven't installed any additional apps in Metro.

I installed Shell32_Patch_Setup_v1.3.exe for getting windows 7 like explorer. (But I cant find the official link for that program in internet now).

EDIT: I tried removing the shell hack and still it is not working. (But I really want to keep it.)

Everything is working perfectly from my current account which I created at the time of installing Windows 8.

My installed list of updates is given below, since I heard some updates causes problems.

```
  Caption                                     CSName      Description      FixComments  HotFixID                                         InstallDate  InstalledBy              InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status  

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2712101     MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2712101_Microsoft-Windows-CameraCodec-Package               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2727528  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2727528                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2729462  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2729462                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2736693  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2736693                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2737084  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2737084                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2742614  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2742614                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2742616  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2742616                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2753842  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2753842                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2756872  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2756872                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2756923  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2756923                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2757638  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2757638                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2758246  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2758246                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2758994  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2758994                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2761094  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2761094                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2764870  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2764870                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2768703  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2768703                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2769034  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2769034                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2769165  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2769165                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2769166  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2769166                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2770660  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2770660                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2770816  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2770816                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/16/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2770917  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2770917                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2771431  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2771431                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2771821  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2771821                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2777166  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2777166                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2777294  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2777294                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2778171  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2778171                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2779562  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2779562                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2779768  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2779768                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2780342  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2780342                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2780523  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2780523                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2781197  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2781197                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2782419  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2782419                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2783251  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2783251                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2784160  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2784160                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2785094  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2785094                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2785220  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2785220                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2788350  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2788350                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2789649  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2789649                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2789650  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2789650                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2790920  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2790920                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2792009  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2792009                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2795944  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2795944                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2798162  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2798162                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2800033  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2800033                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2800088  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2800088                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2803821  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2803821                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2804583  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2804583                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2804584  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2804584                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2805222  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2805222                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2805227  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2805227                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2805966  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2805966                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2807986  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2807986                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2808679  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2808679                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2811660  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2811660                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2812829  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2812829                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2813430  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2813430                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2820197  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2820197                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2820330  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2820330                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2821895  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2821895                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2822241  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2822241                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2823233  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2823233                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/13/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2829254  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2829254                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2829361  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2829361                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2830290  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2830290                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2832418  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2832418                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2833958  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2833958                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2833959  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2833959                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2835361  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2835361                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2835364  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2835364                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2836946  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2836946                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2836947  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2836947                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2836988  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2836988                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2839894  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2839894                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2840632  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2840632                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2840633  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2840633                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2844289  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2844289                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2845187  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2845187                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2845533  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2845533                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2845690  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2845690                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2846071  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2846071                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2850674  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2850674                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2850851  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2850851                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2851234  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2851234                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2853915  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2853915                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2855336  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2855336                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2856758  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2856758                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2857645  MAHESHWARY  Security Update               KB2857645                                                     maheshwary\Harikrishnan  7/11/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2859541  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2859541                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2862073  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2862073                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013                                       

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2864629  MAHESHWARY  Update                        KB2864629                                                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      7/18/2013
```

Comment: Get rid of the shell hack and see if the problem resolves itself.

Comment: Oh I missed that point. I already tried that.

Comment: Do you have a restore point from before you installed the shell hack?

Comment: No. I haven't created a restore point.

Answer (score 1):

boot from Win8 DVD and run `DISM /Image:C:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` to restore damaged and corrupted Windows system files.

Comment: I ran the sfc tool to find the missing files. but it reported no errors

Comment: @Hari - Did you run the command that Andre suggested?

Comment: I tried that. It fixed the problem, but the shell customization is gone. I think the shell hack uninstaller was not restored the shell32.dll. But is there any ways to get both working?

Comment: please don't use themes which modify system files like shell32.dll, this only causes issues. Be happy that the damaged files are restored correctly.